# Generating a list of IP addresses in a Bash loop

Tags: bash

I need a list of IP addresses from 130.15.0.0 to 130.15.255.255. I tried this but I realized it will create 255 lists. Can anyone please help me figure this out?

```
for (( i = 0; i <= 255; i++)) ; do
for (( j = 0; j <= 255; j++)) ; do
LIST="$LIST 130.15.$i.$j"
done
done
```

Comment: Can you add the output you're getting and explaining why it's not the output you expected?

Comment: It looks like it creates 256 * 256 = 65536 IPs. So, what's wrong?

Comment: @Benjamin W. answers K.U's problem with elegance, but the answer to K.U's question can be found here (spoiler: `LIST+=("130.15.$i.$j")` with `declare -a LIST=()` above the loops)  http://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/211395/in-a-loop-over-an-array-add-an-el
ement-to-the-array

Answer (score 32, accepted):

I'd say that your approach works, but it is very slow<sup>1</sup>. You can use brace expansion instead:

```
echo 135.15.{0..255}.{0..255}
```

Or, if you want the result in a variable, just assign:

```
list=$(echo 135.15.{0..255}.{0..255})
```

If you want the addresses in an array, you can skip the `echo` and command substitution:

```
list=(135.15.{0..255}.{0..255})
```

Now, `list` is a proper array:

```
$ echo "${list[0]}"                    # First element
135.15.0.0
$ echo "${list[@]:1000:3}"             # Three elements in the middle
135.15.3.232 135.15.3.233 135.15.3.234
```

---

Comments on your code:

- Instead of

  ```
  list="$list new_element"
  ```

  it is easier to append to a string with

  ```
  list+=" new_element"
  ```
- If you wanted to append to an array in a loop, you'd use

  ```
  list+=("new_element")
  ```
- Uppercase variable names are not recommended as they're more likely to clash with environment variables (see [POSIX spec](http://pubs.opengroup.org/onlinepubs/9699919799/basedefs/V1_chap08.html), paragraph four)

---

<sup>1</sup> In fact, on my machine, it takes almost six minutes – the brace expansion takes less than 0.1 seconds!